# if elif not working properly for else clause in bash script

Tags: bash, if-statement

I am facing an issue using if elif in bash ,my program is written below,i am careful about the spaces

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo "enter a number"
read num
if (( num >= 1 )) && (( num < 10 )); then
echo "sam"
elif (( num >= 10 )) && (( num < 90 )); then
echo "ram"
elif (( num >= 90 )) && (( num  < 100 )); then
echo "rahim"
else
echo "tara"
fi
```

output:

```
sourav@LAPTOP-HDM6QEG8:~$ bash ifelse2.sh
enter a number
5
sam
sourav@LAPTOP-HDM6QEG8:~$ bash ifelse2.sh
enter a number
15
ram
sourav@LAPTOP-HDM6QEG8:~$ bash ifelse2.sh
enter a number
95
rahim
sourav@LAPTOP-HDM6QEG8:~$ bash ifelse2.sh
enter a number
105
ifelse2.sh: line 11: echo tara: command not found
```

So every if and elif works except for the else part,I am extra careful about spaces ,however still I am getting an error ,can someone help,thanks in advance

Comment: I suspect you have _unbreakable space_ between `echo` and `tara`. Replace it with a standard space.

Comment: thanks for the help Gilles,I put two spaces between echo and "tara" and the problem solved,however I like to know why one space is not enough,strange really

Comment: I cut-n-pasted your code into my environment and when entering `105` it prints `tara`, ie, the code works as expected and *no* error message is displayed; at this point I have to assume that either a) the code you've presented here is not the same as what's in your script or b) there are some non-printing characters in your script that could be causing an issue; if you're unable to resolve the issue then consider doing the following ... run `base64 ifelse2.sh` and update the question with the entire output from said command ... from this we can reconstitute your exact script in our environment

Comment: base64 ifelse2.sh
IyEvdXNyL2Jpbi9iYXNoCmVjaG8gImVudGVyIGEgbnVtYmVyIgpyZWFkIG51bQppZiAoKCBudW0g
Pj0gMSApKSAmJiAoKCBudW0gPCAxMCApKTsgdGhlbgplY2hvICJzYW0iCmVsaWYgKCggbnVtID49
IDEwICkpICYmICgoIG51bSA8IDkwICkpOyB0aGVuCmVjaG8gInJhbSIKZWxpZiAoKCBudW0gPj0g
OTAgKSkgJiYgKCggbnVtICA8IDEwMCApKTsgdGhlbgplY2hvICJyYWhpbSIKZWxzZQplY2hvICJ0
YXJhIgpmaQoK

Comment: is that the `base64` output from the broken or fixed script? when I run `base64 -d -i` in my environment I get a workable script (ie, entering `105` also generates `tara` ... no error message)

Comment: Try `grep tara ifelse2.sh | od -cx`, you should get something like ` e   c   h   o       "   t   a   r   a   "  \n` and on the next line `6563    686f    2022    7461    7261    220a`. The `20` is a normal space. When you get `6365    6f68    2220    6174    6172    0a22` you need the `od` parameter `--endian` with arguments `little` or `big`.

Comment: What you think is a space, is certainly not a space in your example. It could be some unicode character which looks like a space, for instance a Japanese half-width space (Codepoint U+FF00). Have a look at your file with a hex-editor.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the spotted problem:

```
perl -i -pe 's/\becho\b\W+\btara\b/echo tara/' ifelse2.sh
```

---

For arithmetic, a better way to code

```
(( num >= 1 )) && (( num < 10 ))
```

is

```
(( num >= 1 && num < 10 ))
```

And **please**, indent your code properly, especially when asking help to others.

Comment: I like to write `(( 1 <= num && num < 10 ))` which is most like the `1 ≤ num < 10` arithmetic notation